# how to get indication of special charater read from file in java

Tags: java, io, inputstream

In java I am writing a code in which I am reading a text file using DataInputStream.read() method and I want to get indication if the character read from the file is other than a digit(0,1,2,...) or alphabet(a,b,c,...). Please help how I can do that?

Comment: see [`Character.isLetterOrDigit()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetterOrDigit-char-)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
char c = //read a char

if( c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'){
 //is a lower case alphabet
}
else if (c >= '0' && c <= '9'){
// is a number
}else{
  //is something else
}
```